# Is there a way robots (from robotport) fill turrets with bullets?

Tags: factorio

I have a lot of gun magazines and logistic robots.

Is there a way I can instruct the robots to fill my turrets automatically with ammunition?

Comment: I think that is half the reason why Laser turrets are in the game, using power instead of bullets.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Not without mods.

If you need to do this and don’t want to use mods, you can just place a requester chest next to each turret and use an inserter to move bullets from the chest into the turrets themselves. (You could also just have the chest unload onto a belt that unloads into turrets if you don’t want to use so many request chests, but in practice there’s not much difference.)

If you *are* willing to use mods, the [Logistic Turrets](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=93&t=20661) mod adds turrets that directly request bullets from the logistics network.

Comment: a more efficient use would be to use conveyors, and perhaps have the bots deliver to just one or two chests and drop them directly form the chests to the conveyors that lead behind all your turrets